# White lines over images in internet explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-11

I have a client that is reporting white lines appearing over her website in IE11. It doesn't happen all the time and we can't replicate it on any of our machines here.

It does sound like an isolated issue but I'd quite like to go back to her with a better answer than that!

Has anyone experienced this before and does anyone know what causes it?

The site is just a basic WordPress site with a bespoke theme, WordPress has been kept up to date but the theme is a few years old now...

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it may be related to the border rendering problem in ie11.  See:  http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/808920/ie11-renders-white-lines-when-border-radius-and-gradients-are-applied-to-buttons

MS also had problems reproducing it, so that may be why you can see it fine but the client can't.    So, try removing some of those effects as a trial case.

Comment: The image is just a div with a  background image and regular border, no border radius or gradients... also the white lines aren't at the edge, there is about 40 off them in varing widths horizontally across the image.